# Using mouse related events in PowerPoint through VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I am creating a PowerPoint 2010 add-in using VSTO. I need to capture mouse related events.

PowerPoint.Application provides three mouse related events.

```
1- Application.WindowBeforeRightClick

2- Application.WindowBeforeDoubleClick

3- Application.WindowSelectionChange
```

Now, according to my working and research(both self and using the internet), I have found that the **Application.WindowBeforeRightClick** and **Application.WindowBeforeDoubleClick** events are not fired in PowerPoint. This is due to some bug that Microsoft hasn't been able to fix since PowerPoint 2007.

Also there are no mouse or chart related events in PowerPoint.Chart object. But, on the other hand, if I use Excel.Chart object then there are many mouse and chart related events(i.e **MouseUp**, **MouseDown**, **MouseOver** etc) to work with.

My question is how can I use these mouse related events on my PowerPoint chart, shapes or on the active slide? Also if there are no such events available in PowerPoint, can I use the Excel.Chart mouse events in my PowerPoint add-in? And most importantly how?